# How to implement a Filter for a Table with php

Tags: php, html-table

I am working on a Overview Table for some Data strugeling on how to implement a Filter Option.

The Table looks like:

```
Process Type | Issue Total | Issue closed | Issue open
Piping       |    20       |     15       |    5
Cable pulling|
```

This are already summarys of individual "items" belonging to the Proces types like piping.

The "Items" are related to Systems.

So now i want to implement a Filter Option to filter the sum of the issues for Piping with the Systems

```
Filter: <select>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
</select>
<button> Filter results</button>

Process Type | Issue Total | Issue closed | Issue open
Piping       |    20       |     15       |    5
Cable pulling|
```

Where do i have my problem?
This Table is one of 6 different tables in one .php file which is included in the content section.
I dont realy know how to execute the filter on this table.

Thanks in advance for any idea/inout

Comment: Can you explain more precisely what you want to achieve? What is meant by the sum? Is it the sum of all three details about Piping? Or do you just want to show entries, which are greater than 1 or 2? Or do you just want to show the piping issues, when someone picks 1 in the select element? Please describe in more detail what should happen if someone clicks on the button.

Comment: If you don’t want to submit a form and reload the whole page, then the alternative is AJAX.

Comment: @Marcel As mentioned in my Post i have several Item Clases.
Piping hast around 800 Items which belong to around 20 different Systems (Each Item 1 System/ 1 System Multiple Items)

In my overviewtable im now showing the sum of all Piping issues, separated by thir status.
Now they want to filter this for the different Systems to see only the piping issues for System 1 or 2 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I 'm not sure, if I got your data model right. But here 's a little example, how to filter data structures with PHP. After the PHP part I will explain, how to set up your HTML form, to just output the wanted items in your HTML table.

### The PHP Part

I assume you read your data from a database table or an API. So let us assume that our model looks like this. This model is just an example to show, how a object oriantated approach in PHP could look like.

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Marcel\Model;

class Item
{
    protected $id;
    protected $systemID;
    protected $anotherProperty;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId(int $id): self
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getSystemId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->systemId;
    }

    public function setSystemId(int $systemId): self
    {
        $this->systemId = $systemId;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getAnotherProperty(): ?string
    {
        return $this->anotherProperty;
    }

    public function setAnotherProperty(string $anotherProperty): self
    {
        $this->anotherProperty = $anotherProperty;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

As you can see our item model just has three properties. The important property will be the system id. We will later filter a collection of items by this property. Before we will do that, we use a collection to store all our item objects. Why this collection? A collection gives us a sort of type safety and makes the handling easier, when it comes to filter the collection.

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Marcel\Model;

use InvalidArgumentException;
use SplObjectStorage;

class ItemCollection extends SplObjectStorage
{
    public function attach($object, $data = null): self
    {
        if (!$object instanceof Item) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf(
                'The given object must be of the type Item. Given: "%s"',
                get_class($object)
            ));
        }

        parent::attach($object, $data);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

This is our item collection. This collection extends the PHP built-in class `SplObjectStorage` and is designed for storing objects. In this case the collection accepts only objects of the type `Item`. Our collection implements the `Iterator` interfacem which makes the collection iterable. Perfectly made for filtering.

The next thing we need will be a filter. PHP brings a built-in `FilterIterator` class, which makes filtering data structures easy as pie.

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Marcel\Filter;

class ItemFilterIterator extends FilterIterator
{
    protected $systemId;

    public function __construct(Iterator $iterator, int $systemId = 0)
    {
        parent::__construct($iterator);
        $this->systemId = $systemId;
    }

    public function accept(): bool
    {
        // if system id is 0 return all items
        if ($this->systemId === 0) {
            return true;
        }

        $item = $this->getInnerIterator()->current();
        return $item->getSystemId() === $this->systemId;
    }
}
```

This is our `FilterIterator` implementation. The extension needs the system ID as a second parameter in the constructur. The system ID will be our filter argument. The `accept` method will return true, when the system id property of an item is equal to the system id filter argument. If not, the accept method returns false.

Let 's see, what this three classes can do for you. Here 's a practicable example. First I will create some items for example purpose.

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namspace Marcel;

use Marcel\Filter\ItemFilterIterator;
use Marcel\Model\Item;
use Marcel\Model\ItemCollection;

$item1 = (new Item())
    ->setId(1)
    ->setSystemId(1)
    ->setAnotherProperty('item 1');

$item2 = (new Item())
    ->setId(2)
    ->setSystemId(1)
    ->setAnotherProperty('item 2');

$item3 = (new Item())
    ->setId(3)
    ->setSystemId(2)
    ->setAnotherProperty('item 3');

$collection = (new ItemCollection())
    ->attach($item1)
    ->attach($item2)
    ->attach($item3);

// here comes the magic
$filter = new ItemFilterIterator($collection, 2);
foreach ($filter as $item) {
    var_dump($item);
}
```

In this example we have three items, which belong to two different systems set by the sysmtem id property. Normally this items should come from your database or whereever your datasets come from. The items were set to the collection, which we filter with the filter iterator class. In this example we just want the items belonging to system 2. With this setting, the foreach loop just outputs the item 3, because the system id equals to 2.

### The HTML Part

Your HTML Template looks right. I 'll extend it a bit for you.

```
<form id="my-filter-form" method="post" action="index.php">
    <label for="filter">Filter</label>
    <select name="filter" id="filter">
        <option value="">all</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Filter results</button>
</form>
```

As you can see, we use a normal form, which will send the selected filter option to a php file called `index.php`. Every time someone hits the "Filter results" button, the form will be send and the page will be refreshed.

Here 's a example index.php file.

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Marcel;

use Marcel\Filter\ItemFilterIterator;
use Marcel\Model\Item;
use Marcel\Model\ItemCollection;

// first get your items from somewhere and fill the item collection
$collection = new ItemCollection();
$collection->attach(...); // attach all the items

// check, if there 's a filter - if not use 0 to display all items
$systemID = (isset($_POST['filter'])) ? intval($_POST['filter']) : 0;

// init the filter iterator
$filter = new ItemFilterIterator($collection, $systemID);
$items = new ItemCollection();

// attach all filtered items to a new collection
foreach ($filter as $item) {
    $items->attach($item);
}
?>

<form id="my-filter-form" method="post" action="index.php">
    <label for="filter">Filter:</label>
    <select id="filter" name="filter">
        <option>all</option>
        <option value="1">system 1</option>
        <option value="2">system 2</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Filter me!</button>
</form>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>System</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($items as $item) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $item->getId() ?></td>
            <td><?= $item->getSystemId() ?></td>
            <td><?= $item->getAnotherProperty() ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Keep in mind, that the page will reload every time you send the form. If you want to avoid the reload you have to use ajax (asynchronous javascript requests).

Hope this small filtering example helps.